# Why +++x will be divided into ++(+x) instead of +(++x) in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

When I type this code bellow

```
int x = 1;
+++x;
```

it would be divided into `++(+x)`, and of course the sentence is wrong cause there's a rvalue after `++`.

I am curious about why it can not be `+(++x)`, in which the code is correct.

Is this depend on the IDE or the compiler ?

Can it be find in C++ Standard ? Or it's just a undefined behaviour ?

Thanks a lot to answer this question and forgive my poor English.

Comment: Check [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: It's known as the "maximum munch" rule. Since `++` is a valid token, the compiler eats the first two `+`s and treats them as the `++` operator. It doesn't go back after it detects a problem to try and see if there was something different it could have done.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except for questions about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Answer (score 7):

From C++20 (draft N4860) `[lex.pptoken]/3.3`

> — Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute
> a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail, ...

and `[lex.pptoken]/6`

> [Example: The program fragment x+++++y is parsed as x ++ ++ + y, which, if x and y have integral types,
> violates a constraint on increment operators, even though the parse x ++ + ++ y might yield a correct
> expression. —end example]

So, it is a rule of the language, that the `+` goes with the variable, because the `++` is first grouped together.

Funnily, this reminds me of an old problem where: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a` used to cause problems because `>>` would be one token instead of two (since it's supposed to be the longest sequence of characters). This is addressed by `[temp.names]/3`

> When a name is considered to be a template-name, and it is followed by a <, the < is always taken as the
> delimiter of a template-argument-list and never as the less-than operator. When parsing a template-argumentlist,
> the first non-nested > is taken as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator. Similarly,
> the first non-nested >> is treated as two consecutive but distinct > tokens, the first of which is taken as the
> end of the template-argument-list and completes the template-id. [Note: The second > token produced by this
> replacement rule may terminate an enclosing template-id construct or it may be part of a different construct
> (e.g., a cast). —end note]

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the **maximum munch tokenization principle**:

> A C++ implementation must collect as many consecutive characters as possible into a token.

From [lex.pptoken#3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.pptoken#3.3):

> Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail, except that a header-name is only formed within a #include directive.

And since `++` is the longest valid token, the parser treats the expression as if `++ +x`.

Comment: This answer quotes text without saying where it is from. If it is not authoritative text, it is of limited value.